# Cannot see rows in unbound DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm trying to pass an unbound DataGridView to a form, and cannot get the rows to appear, even though the Rows.Count value is correct. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

```
// method code
// Create an DataGridView
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Columns.Add("Name","Name");
dgv.Columns.Add("Comments", "Comments");

// Add rows to datagridview
int n = dgv.Rows.Add();
dgv.Rows[n].Cells["Name"].Value = "a test name";
dgv.Rows[n].Cells["Comments"].Value = "some comment";

// Pass DataGridView to form
test_PassingDataGridView f = new test_PassingDataGridView();
f.DataGridTest = dgv;
f.ShowDialog();


// test_PassingDataGridView form code
DataGridView _datagridtest;
public DataGridView DataGridTest
{
    get { return _datagridtest; }
    set { _datagridtest = value; }
}

public test_PassingDataGridView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void test_PassingDataGridView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1 = _datagridtest; // _datagridtest.Rows.Count is correct at this point
}
```

Comment: Samuel Neff's answer is almost certainly correct - it does however appear that you have a datagridview on the form already - your this.dataGridView1. You can simply apply all the code you have currently working on dvg to datagridview1 instead - after InitializeComponent() which is where the new grid is instantiated by the designer generated code behind

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the `DataGridView` to the form.  Put a `DataGridView` on the form in the designer and then pass a `DataTable` to the form and have the form bind the `DataTable` to the `DataGridView`.

By creating the `DataGridView` as you have you're missing a lot of properties that would often be set in the designer.  You can make it work by setting the properties, particularly position and size, but even then it's really bad form to pass controls around like that.  Pass data instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I like the concept of passing data rather than controls and will give it a try.